# Angular 14.2.11 with Docker Compose: How to fix ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on 'front.app.test'?

Tags: docker-compose, angular14

please if you can help me with this issue.

**I created a dockerfile.app:**

```
FROM node:16.10.0-alpine

By default build image for production
ARG BUILD_ENV=prod

ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

RUN apk update

Re-map host user to www-data
RUN if [ ${USER_ID:-0} -ne 0 ] && [ ${GROUP_ID:-0} -ne 0 ] ; then \
apk --no-cache add shadow && \
groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} node && \
usermod -u ${USER_ID} -g ${GROUP_ID} node && \
apk del -f shadow \
>     ;fi

Dependencies required to build node-sass package
RUN apk --no-cache add g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++ linux-headers make python3

Add make and zip for build script to work
RUN apk add --no-cache git make zip

Add useful extension
RUN apk add --no-cache vim curl

Setup working directory
WORKDIR /app

Set permissions for app directory
RUN chown node:node /app

Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package.json package.json

Install project dependencies
RUN npm install

Install the Angular CLI globally
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.11

Copy the rest of the project files
COPY . .

ENV NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=false

EXPOSE 8181
Now volume is mounted in dev and we should install and build everything for dev here
CMD sh -c "(cd /app && yarn install --no-bin-links && yarn build && rm -rf ./node_modules/.cache && ng serve --public-host=front.app.test --host=front.app.test --port 8181 --disable-host-check)"
```

**Also docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  front-app:
    container_name: front-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile.app
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-0}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-0}
        BUILD_ENV: dev
    tty: true
    user: node
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "8181:4200"
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.front-app.rule=Host(`front.app.test`)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-web
    environment:
      - EXCLUDED_PLUGINS=${EXCLUDED_PLUGINS:-""}
    networks:
      - app-network
      - traefik-aptilo-web

  front-nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17.8-alpine
    depends_on:
      - front-app
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/conf/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80"
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.front-nginx.rule=Host(`front-nginx.docker.test`)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-web
    networks:
      - app-network
      - traefik-web



# Define internal network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
  traefik-web:
    external: true
```

**And added this "host" and "port" in angular.json file:**

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "portal-base-frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "portal-base-frontend:build:development",
              "host": "front.app.test",
              "port": 8181
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

**But I'm still getting:**

```
front.app.test didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? I am using Angular 14.2.11

I tried a lot of possible solutions but nothing worked for me.